# SQL error reporting by mail

Tags: php, sql, drupal, report

I was wondering if its possible to have some kind of SQL error reporting that sends me an email that includes the error and the website that it's been found on.

I'd like to take this precaution because of hosting multiple drupal systems.

There is a PHP error variant:

http://drupal.org/project/php_errors

Hope you guys know a way to become aware of any possible SQL errors by not loggin in to check the error report.

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL?
What type of "errors"?

Depending on how you handle/log errors you can configure a periodic SQL job to email you the results of a query.

Comment: A thing im concerned about most is querys that are not succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround

```
try{
   // Code
}catch(Exception $e){
   // Exception management
}
```

all your code with a php mailing function in the catch side. Thus you have the automatic reporting you are looking for, without using any automating software.